# Getting JRuby to work in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, rubymine

I setup the proper SDK because all my ruby code will compile but RubyMine complains that
it can't find the any of my java classes? Is this a flaw or is there a way to get it to recognizewhere the classes are?

Here is my code, I have underlined all the things its complaining about

```
require 'java'

include_class 'java.awt.event.ActionListener'
include_class 'javax.swing.JButton'
include_class 'javax.swing.JFrame'

class ClickAction
  include ActionListener

  def action_performed(event)
    puts "Button got clicked."
  end
end
```

Is there a way around this because I'd love to buy RubyMine if it's able to inform me of what Java
classes and methods I can pick from.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RubyMine does not have any support for Java and does not recognize Java classes - JRuby is only supported as a target platform for running regular Ruby code. Full Java/Ruby interoperability is supported in IntelliJ IDEA with the Ruby plugin.

Comment: Thanks... that saves me some frustration

Comment: But does IDEA supports Rails and everything else RubyMine supports (Cucumber, Rspec, RubyOnRails, Haml, Sass etc)?

Comment: New features usually appear in RubyMine before the Ruby plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, but eventually the plugin catches up with RubyMine. The version available now for IDEA 9 does support all of the listed features.